# Efficiently select all many-to-many pairs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Seems like a simple query to do but the resulting SQL has something like one query per row (3000+ lines long).

I have a many-to-many association with no intermediate entity type. I am using LazyLoading.

Entities are something like this:

```
public class Entity1 {
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Entity2> Entity2s { get; } = new List<Entity2>();
}

public class Entity2 {
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Entity1> Entity1s { get; } = new List<Entity1>();
}

...

entity1Builder
.HasMany(e1 => e1.Entity2s)
.WithMany(e2 => e2.Entity1s);
```

And then the query is like:

```
from e1 in Entity1s
from e2 in e1.Entity2s
select new {
   Entity1 = e1,
   Entity2 = e2
}
```

Other forms I've tried have the same result:

```
from e1 in Entity1s
from e2 in Entity2s
where e1.Entity2s.Contains(e2)
select new {
   Entity1 = e1,
   Entity2 = e2
}
```

```
Entity1s
.SelectMany(e1 =>
   e1
   .Entity2s
   .Select(e2 => new {
      Entity1 = e1,
      Entity2 = e2
   })
)
```

Is it not possible to do this in such a way that it does a single join between the two tables (or well, two joins between the three tables, but just once)? Even just `Entity1s.SelectMany(e1 => e1.Entity2s)` has the same problem of O(n) queries.

Theoretically the SQL should be able to look something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM JoinTable jt
INNER JOIN Entity1s e1s ON jt.Entity1ID = e1s.ID
INNER JOIN Entity2s e2s ON jt.Entity2ID = e2s.ID
...
```

Instead it seems to do an `INNER JOIN` between `Entity1s` and `Entity2s` directly, but then enumerates the results and does a lookup query for every single result. So that's actually O(n x m) queries (size of E1 times size of E2). (Actually it *seems* like it's doing even more than that, eagerly loading nav properties that I haven't specified.

I've now also tried using an intermediate entity, but it still has the same results.

```
JoinEntity
.Select(j => new {
   j.Entity1,
   j.Entity2
})
```

I think what is happening is that it is "eager" loading the entities one by one due to the anonymous projection that uses the entity references. I'm pretty sure in older EF versions you used to be able to project this way and it would populate the entities and properties from the results of a main query, not each one individually. If for example, I just project to fields of the entities, I DO get a nice single query instead:

```
JoinEntity
.Select(j => new {
   j.Entity1.Property1,
   j.Entity2.Property2
})
```

but I would like to get whole entities out of this. I'm pretty sure you used to be able to do this, but maybe I'm wrong.

Another variant, same results:

```
from j in JoinEntity
join e1 in Entity1s on j.Entity1ID equals e1.ID
join e2 in Entity2s on j.Entity2ID equals e2.ID
select new { e1, e2 }
```

Comment: what about `Include`? it was meant to solve `N + 1` problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a simple `LINQ` query that makes use of `EF`'s `Include` statement.

I would suggest the following:

```
var e1ande2pairs = await dbContext.Entity1
    .Include(a => a.Entity2s)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Entity1s)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Entity2s, (entity1, entity2) => new { Entity1 = entity1, Entity2 = entity2 })
    .ToListAsync();
```

This should result in a single round-trip to the `SQL Server` and should return the results that you're looking for.

Comment: `.ThenInclude(check => check.To.akseli).In(mail)` :)

Comment: hmm, this has the same issue with O(n+) queries. trying these on EF Playground, it seems to work in the simple case, using one `CROSS APPLY` query. for some reason my actual model seems to eagerly load all related entities, I'm not sure why. (there are queries to load related entities that I haven't even referred to.)

Comment: I think it is related to `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` which requires `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`. If I turn that off I can get it in a single query. but my whole design is based around lazy loading.

Comment: Yeah, that's what lazy loading does. As soon as you address a navigation property in an entity, it's loaded. If you `Include` entities then only the `Included` navigations are marked as loaded (and won't lazy load) and all other navigations will get loaded whenever they're addressed.